# Where can I find the alien weapon?

Tags: fallout-3

I'm wondering where to find the alien weapon in fallout 3.
A friend of mine played a new game and put it on very difficult and then he went to Super Duper Mart. He found some raiders, killed them and took a "Flaming spear" gun with alien energy as ammo.
I cannot find it in my game.
Is it because I play on normal difficulty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be talking about the [Firelance](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Firelance). You can read up on it and how to get it in the link. Basically it is a part of a random drop encounter.

Answer (score 1):

It could also be the [Alien Blaster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Blaster), which is very similar to the Firelance but easier to acquire. You have to get it from a crashed spaceship (which is very radioactive.)

> The Alien Blaster can be obtained next
>   to the body of a dead alien lying a
>   few feet away from his crashed
>   spaceship. The Alien Crash Site is
>   found due north of MDPL-13 Power
>   Station and northwest of the Greener
>   Pastures Disposal Site. There are only
>   120 Alien Power Cells found at the
>   crash site. A few cells may be
>   obscured by the ground (standing
>   vertically and partially underground).

Comment: The alien blaster is so cool.  I love that gun.