# How much alien blaster ammo is there in Fallout 3?

Tags: fallout-3

One of the reasons I never cared for the alien blaster (and never went after the [firelance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/fallout-3-alien-weapon)) was that the ammo and repair part supply for both seemed ... lacking. Really lacking.

I don't remember any (or much) being in Mothership Zeta, either.

How much is there actually in the game (without the benefit the scavenger perk), both in the regular game and Mothership Zeta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the Wiki article for the ammo: [Alien Power Cell](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_Power_Cell)

(That link also contains the locations.)

In the core game:

> 362 power cells.

Entirely:

> A maximum of 1152 alien power cells can be found in all expansions, without the raider glitch.

In Mothership Zeta, there are:

> 365 power cells.

Comment: Apparently I didn't do enough exploration ... That's about 6 or 7 times as much as I'd ever found total ... :)